# How to get the json message on this callback

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jeditable

I'm trying to make some changes to the way jEditable handles errors. I have a PHP function which is returning:

```
echo "{'error':'ok', 'error_msg':'There was a problem'}";
```

in my javascript:

```
"callback": function( sValue, y ) 
                      {
                        if (sValue == "ok")
                        {
                          alert ("ok");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          alert ("error");
                        }},
```

Now I keep getting the "error" alert on my screen - no matter what I try. Obviously the problem is at this line:

```
if (sValue == "ok")
```

but I'm not sure what it is supposed to be? I've looked at other examples on StackOverflow - but couldnt get one that answered my question.

Comment: Is `sValue` the entire returned `JSON`? If so you should use `sValue.error == 'ok'`.

Comment: You may have to parse the returned JSON string into an JS object before using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you need to parse JSON and get `error` value from parsed object:

```
"callback": function (data, y) {
    var errorData = $.parseJSON(data);
    if (errorData.error == "ok") {
        alert("ok");
    } else {
        alert("error");
    }
},
```